# Send from data from .jsp file to a javascript function in aome .jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

The following is OneEmployee.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<form>
   <td> <c:out value="${emp.getEmpid()}"/></td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="fname" value="<c:out value="${emp.getFname()}"/>"></td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="lname" value="<c:out value="${emp.getLname()}"/>"></td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="dob" value="<c:out value="${emp.getDob()}"/>"></td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="salary" value="<c:out value="${emp.getSalary()}"/>"></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="update(<c:out value="${emp.getEmpid()}"/>)">Update</button></td>
</form>
```

Following is Welcome.jsp //homepage JSP

```
<script>  
   function update(id) {
      var empid = "?empid=" + id;
      var formdata = "xyz";
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
      var salary = document.getElementById("salary").value;
      var paramlist = "?empid=" + empid + "&fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname + "&dob=" + dob + "&salary=" + salary;
      $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         data: formdata,
         url: "UpdateEmployee" + paramlist,
         success: function (data) {
            $('#row' + id).html(data);
         }
     });
   }
</script>
```

Following is a java servlet UpdateEmployee.java

```
String id = request.getParameter("empid");
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
    String sal = request.getParameter("salary");
    double salary = Double.parseDouble(sal);
    int empid = Integer.parseInt(id);
```

I am trying to fetch input data from OneEmployee.jsp in update() of Welcome.jsp and send the data to servlet UpdateEmployee.java.
Glassfish server responds:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[UpdateEmployee]: Servlet.service() for servlet UpdateEmployee threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

What is the problem? what went wrong in here? Why is the OneEmployee.jsp passing empty strings to Welcome.jsp and hence UpdateEmployee,jsp?

Comment: Did you check the actual request? Open the browser console with F12, make the requests and then check in the network tab if all parameters are really set.

Comment: No, it says "internal server error" for UpdateEmployee.java servlet

Comment: That's the response. We would like to know what you're actually sending to the server. What's the request's URL (as you are passing the parameter through a url query)?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse an empty String so the exception is thrown :

the problem Is that you're getting an empty value from Front end code ( ajax req  ) . ( recheck in browser console before send ) .

Check first if it's not `null` or `empty` when you parse  otherewise return 0:

```
String id = request.getParameter("empid");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
String sal = request.getParameter("salary");

double salary = 0;
if (sal != null && sal.length() > 0) {
    try{
       salary = Double.parseDouble(sal);
    }catch(Exception e) {
       salary = 0;
    }
}

int empid = 0;
if (id != null && id.length() > 0) {

    try{
       empid = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }catch(Exception e) {
       empid = 0;
    }
}
```